# Can Unnest filtered in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab, unnest

I have a table that has values where the "TAHUN" column group by date_part('year'::text, insert_date) and the value of 1000 in the column "TAHUN" as total

[image: 1]

I want to transpose rows to columns like this (but the "TAHUN" column remains dynamic so I don't have to manually insert it at the turn of the year" :

[image: 2]

I'm confused about filtering by column "TAHUN" with unnest. This is My Query :

```
SELECT
    unnest(array['PENDAPATAN', 'PENJUALAN 1', 'PENJUALAN 2', 'PENDAPATAN LAIN-LAIN', 'TOTAL PENDAPATAN', 'HARGA POKOK PENJUALAN (HPP)', 'PEMBELIAN', 'ONGKOS KIRIM']) AS "title",
    unnest(array["PENDAPATAN", "PENJUALAN 1", "PENJUALAN 2", "PENDAPATAN LAIN-LAIN", "TOTAL PENDAPATAN", "HARGA POKOK PENJUALAN (HPP)", "PEMBELIAN", "ONGKOS KIRIM"]) FILTER (WHERE "TAHUN" != 1000) AS "dynamic year",
    unnest(array["PENDAPATAN", "PENJUALAN 1", "PENJUALAN 2", "PENDAPATAN LAIN-LAIN", "TOTAL PENDAPATAN", "HARGA POKOK PENJUALAN (HPP)", "PEMBELIAN", "ONGKOS KIRIM"]) FILTER (WHERE "TAHUN" = 1000) AS "total"
FROM vw_blm_dashboard_hasil_usaha
GROUP BY "title", "dynamic year", "total";
```

Can unnest filtered? or Do you have any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks before

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the unnesting into the FROM clause, so that you get columns that you can reference.

I personally find writing this using a VALUES clause a bit easier to read:

```
SELECT
    x.title ,
    max(x.value) FILTER (WHERE v."TAHUN" = 2019) AS "2019",
    max(x.value) FILTER (WHERE v."TAHUN" = 2020) AS "2020",
    max(x.value) FILTER (WHERE v."TAHUN" = 2021) AS "2021",
    max(x.value) FILTER (WHERE v."TAHUN" = 1000) AS "total"
FROM vw_blm_dashboard_hasil_usaha v
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL (  
     values ("PENDAPATAN", 'PENDAPATAN'), 
            ("PENJUALAN 1", 'PENJUALAN 1'), 
            ("PENJUALAN 2", 'PENJUALAN 2'), 
            ... all other columns come here ...
 ) as x(value, title)
GROUP BY x.title;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What about dynamic years? So I don't have to insert manually if tomorrow is 2023. Is it possible?

Comment: @Mr.Robot: no that's not possible. you will have to write one expression for every year you want.